# How validate all items in PageableListView in Wicket?

Tags: java, listview, pagination, wicket

In form I use **PageableListView** to iterate TextFields. But when I submit form it only validate current page of PageableListView. Also when I back to eg. Page 1 all values I filled disappear.

When I change PageableListView to standard ListView all works fine – validation and submitting.

I set in ListView: setReuseItems(true).

How validate all items in PageableListView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only validate items that are in the form, on the screen. If you wish to validate stuff on the first page, I think you need a (ajax)FormSubmittingBehavior on the paging controls, so your form is submitted each time you navigate to another page.

If you submit the data, it will also be stored if there are no validation errors.